# Perform two actions on the press of an IconButton

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I am working on a music player, and on pressing next button I want to perform two functions one is to add song to the queue and another function is used to trigger the plugin method of 'addSong'. On button pressed I wish to execute two functions which are '_pageManager.addSong' and 'addSongToQueue'.

This is the code

```
ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
          valueListenable: _pageManager.isLastSongNotifier,
          builder: (_, isLast, __) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next),
              onPressed: (isLast)
                  ? _pageManager.addSong
                  : _pageManager.onNextSongButtonPressed;
            );
          }),
```

Comment: Do you mean by OnPress executing two functions at the same time? why don't you create another function that executes both and pass that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your logic
I might suggest to create a function

```
void onAddSong() {
  _pageManager.addSong();

  // addSongToQueue()
}
```

Then call this

```
onPressed: (isLast)
   ? this.onAddSong
   : _pageManager.onNextSongButtonPressed;
);
```

I'd suggest you to think in the scalability of this widget with that isLast @param, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a ternary, and instead just use a function body.

```
onPressed: () {
  function1();
  function2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if in the oppressed function like this

```
 onPressed: (){
  if(isLast){
    _pageManager.addSong
   }else{                                            
    _pageManager.onNextSongButtonPressed;
   }
 }
```

or use it like this if you have to check only one condition

```
 onPressed: () =>
  isLast ? _pageManager.addSong
   :                                           
 _pageManager.onNextSongButtonPressed;
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
      valueListenable: _pageManager.isLastSongNotifier,
      builder: (_, isLast, __) {
        return IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next),
          onPressed: () {

              // Adding Song
              _pageManager.addSong;

              // Button was Pressed
              _pageManager.onNextSongButtonPressed;
      }),
```